# Different Image on Mouseover

Tags: wordpress, image, mouseover, visual-composer

I am currently working in Wordpress usnig the Visual Composer. I wish to make an image simply change on mouseover for now. I have read many different ways of doing this with Java and CSS but nothing seems to be specifically for this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Working example checks it , replace images with your own.

```
 <a class="foo" href="#">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/1/" />
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/2/" />
 </a>

 <style>
    .foo img:last-child{display:none}
    .foo:hover img:first-child{display:none}
    .foo:hover img:last-child{display:inline-block}
 </style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gd8ba/light/

```
Thanks
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13719971)

Comment: sorry for mistake..!

Answer (score 0):

Say, I have a link -

```
<a class="my-link" href="http://www.my-website.com"></a>
```

I need to show an image on mouse over this link. So, I will add two things in my CSS-

1. To add image to the link

   ```
   .ge-link { background-image: url('http://my-website.com/my-img.png'); background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat;}
   ```
2. To add hovering property

   ```
   .ge-link:hover { background-image: url('http://my-website.com/my-img-hover.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;}
   ```

Comment: Thank you. So, where exactly should I place this? Sorry, I have a lot to learn. Within Visual Composer I can place CSS per page for certain elements. Otherwise, should this go somewhere within my style sheet?

Comment: It can go to the pages where you need to use this property. https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/. Also, accept this as answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but recently I had the same inquiry, so I found this plugin https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/image-over-image-vc-extension/. I've tested it with WPBakery on WP 5.6.3 and it works fine.

Here are the [demos](http://wpbakeryaddons.com/). Hope it works for anyone needing this functionality.